# lintr error in ESS mode with Flycheck

Tags: emacs, ess, flycheck

I have met a problem about Flycheck in ESS mode(Emacs Speak Statistics). Whenever I open a R file, an error occurs, that is, "Suspicious state from syntax checker r-lintr: Checker r-lintr returned non-zero exit code 1, but no errors from output: error in library(lintr): there is no program called lintr ".

But from https://github.com/jimhester/lintr, he says "lintr is fully integrated into flycheck when using ESS". My Flycheck version is 0.25 and ESS version is 15.09, both are the latest ones!

I reinstall ESS but the error remains. Finally I have to disable syntax checker and the error is gone.

Have anyone met similar problem?Can anyone give any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question seems to be a silly one! You just need to install "lintr" package in your R session first. The solution came from Jonathan H in the now dead Google+ Emacs Community (link removed)

```
install.packages("lintr")
```